# Reproducing an SVG figure

Tags: svg

I'm preparing for an exam and one of the questions on a previous exam was to reproduce this figure in SVG (dimensions can be freely chosen):

[image]

So far, i was successfull but currently i'm stuck. I can't seem to be able to 'chop' off the figure on the bottom:
[image]

This is the code i used:

```
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="...">
    <svg width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
       <defs>
           <g id="circle">
              <circle r="100px" cx="0" cy="0" />
           </g>
       </defs>

       <use xlink:href="#circle" x="0" y="75"/>
       <use xlink:href="#circle" transform="translate(200,75)"/>
    </svg>
 </svg>
```

I've tried messing around with the `viewBox`, but to no avail.
Any help/tips/advice appreciated.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what (wonderful) course exam is asking you to hand-code SVG?

Comment: @Phrogz The course is called Document Processing and in the first few chapters XML and XSLT (amongst other things) are introduced. The SVG part is a very, very small part of the course. In this exercise we got a representation of the figure in XML for which we had to write an XSLT to transform the XML to the SVG code. It's not too hard and i can assume not many people code svg by hand :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to adjust your `height` attribute as well as the `viewBox`:

```
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <svg width="200" height="150" viewBox="0 0 200 150">
       <defs>
           <g id="circle">
              <circle r="100px" cx="0" cy="0" />
           </g>
       </defs>

       <use xlink:href="#circle" x="0" y="75"/>
       <use xlink:href="#circle" transform="translate(200,75)"/>
    </svg>
 </svg>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VJcwx/

Comment: I *knew* it had to be something with the `viewBox`, ah well at least i was close :). Thanks a lot!